# How to easily split screen space to fit two windows in Ubuntu 20.04.4

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04.4 on my system but when i try to split the screen to use two windows, nothing is happening. I have use these combinations: Ctrl+Super+left/right arrow key

- ctrl+super+←
- ctrl+super+→

I want to code using vs code as i see changes on chrome simultaneously

Answer (score 18):

Try Super + Arrow key instead

- super+←
- super+→

[image]

Comment: super key = windows key, In case anyone's wondering.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `windows(super)-key` + `arrow keys` to move and splitt screens.

If you wanna split your filemanager try use `F3` key.

If you wanna see changes from vs code editor in chrome without reload page on the
browser manually you need to config a `live server` in `vs code editor`.

Check this for `live server` in `vs code editor`:

[VSCode Auto Reload Browser during code change](https://www.hmtmcse.com/dev-bismillah/vs-code/auto-reload)

[VS Code Live Server – How to Auto-Refresh Your Browser with this Simple Extension](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/vscode-live-server-auto-refresh-browser/)